# Cordova 9: browser-sync alternatives

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, browser-sync

The cordova plugin [Browser-sync](https://github.com/nparashuram/cordova-plugin-browsersync) has been archived and it doesn't work anymore using cordova 9 (the cordova app does not compile anymore).

Is there any working alternative?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried https://evothings.com/doc/build/cordova-guide.html#Workflow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm quite late answering, but I have forked good old cordova-plugin-browsersync and made it compatible with Cordova 9 along with few improvements. Fork is called cordova-plugin-browsersync-gen2 and it's already available in npm.

Github repo: https://github.com/DimitrisRK/cordova-plugin-browsersync-gen2

Comment: Thank you @DnR - it works like a charm, great work. But I couldn't find the Issues tab in your GitHub andI can't figure out how to ignore multiple paths (I tried `--ignore=[**/*.svg,**/*.png]` and a few regex for instance)... Any ideas?

Comment: @MathieuCastets Hello, thank you for posting this. Could you try using 'ignore' parameter like this? ```--ignore="**/*.svg, **/*.png"```

Comment: Hi @DnR, this didn't work but I eventually found out that adding multiple `--ignore ` works:
for instance: `--ignore=lib/**/*.* --ignore=assets/**`